# React.js sort data in useEffect

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting, use-effect, use-state

I have a useState hook name stories.

```
const [stories, setStories] = useState([
{
      name: "1st Story",
      sid: 1,
      apartmentDetails: [],
},{
      name: "2nd Story",
      sid: 2,
      apartmentDetails: [],
}
]);
```

Now I want to add **apartmentDetails** in **1st Story**. To achieve this functionality I am doing the following.

```
let story = stories.find((story) => story.sid == storyID);
    const storyWithDetails = {
      ...story,
      appartmentDetails: [
        ...story.appartmentDetails,
        {
          apartment_name: apratmentName,
          apartment_num: apratmentNum,
          apartment_type: apartmentType,
          areaDetails: [],
        },
      ],
```

But it's rearranging the stories by putting the **1st Story** at the last of the array.
I used useEffect hook to sort it

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setStories(stories.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.sid) - parseInt(b.sid)));
    console.log(stories);
  }, [stories]);
```

the log is returning me the sorted stories but in HTML/JSX it's not working.

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't work, what's your output in the page

Comment: Yeah. Not getting sorted stories in page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.sort()` sorts the array **in-place.**

Try storing it to another variable and setting the state.

Like,

```
useEffect(() => {
    const newStories = [...stories];
    newStories.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.sid) - parseInt(b.sid));
    setStories(newStories);
  }, [stories]);
```

**Caution:** `setStories()` inside a `useEffect()` with dependency as `[stories]` can cause infinite loop. But the core idea is same above.

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Not Working the cdode

Comment: Did you try the edited code too? Isn't that too working?

Comment: If I edit it works but it should work automatically

Comment: array.sort returns a sorted array as well actually.. right?

Comment: @HamzaAfzal the edited code works because you are basically using the mutated array. React doesnt understand that the state has changed if you mutate the state. So you need to use the spread operator to create a new array and the sort that array

Comment: it went into infinity loop

Comment: That's because you are having [stories] as dependency

Comment: Then what will be the solution of this

Comment: Sort it when you are updating the state anywhere out of useEffect